# For Nested Loops in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, nested-loops

I have a For loop to look at columns and need to skip two columns. When I run this code, the second For loop (with iCol) does not work.

The code within the loop works fine when I tested outside of the loop. I have tried different options to exclude the two columns from the For loop (select case) but nothing works.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim n As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim NameColNum As Integer
Dim LNameColNum As Integer
Dim DoBColNum As Integer
Dim SColNum As Integer
Dim JColNum As Integer

' Sets data range
Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

NameColNum = Application.Match("First Name", rng.EntireRow(1), 0)
LNameColNum = Application.Match("Last Name", rng.EntireRow(1), 0)
DoBColNum = Application.Match("Birth Date", rng.EntireRow(1), 0)

' For S and J cases
SColNum = Application.Match("Created User ID", rng.EntireRow(1), 0)
JColNum = Application.Match("W Name", rng.EntireRow(1), 0)

For iRow = 2 To rng.Rows.Count

If rng.Cells(iRow, NameColNum) = rng.Cells(iRow + 1, NameColNum) And _
   rng.Cells(iRow, LNameColNum) = rng.Cells(iRow + 1, LNameColNum) And _
   rng.Cells(iRow, DoBColNum) = rng.Cells(iRow + 1, DoBColNum) Then

        If rng.Cells(iRow, SColNum).Value = "STAGE" Then
            rng.EntireRow(iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            rng.EntireRow(iRow + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

        If rng.Cells(iRow, JColNum) = "Smith" Then
                rng.EntireRow(iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                rng.EntireRow(iRow + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If

        For iCol = DoBColNum + 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If iCol <> SColNum And iCol <> JColNum Then
                If rng.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value <> rng.Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).Value And _
                    rng.EntireRow(iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
                    rng.EntireRow(iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = iCol
                    rng.EntireRow(iRow + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = iCol
                End If
            End If
        Next 'iCol
End If
Next 'iRow
```

Comment: I dont see where you assigned `SColNum` and `JColNum` a column index. You can just use the column Index directly and do without those variables. If you are skipping columns A & B you can use, `If iCol <> 1 And iCol <> 2 Then`

Comment: Where is rng set? This shouldn't loop at all. Put option explicit at the top of your module.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work. Have you set breakpoints in the code. Is the outer for loop executing at all?

Comment: Thank you! I used SColNum = Application.Match("Created User ID", rng.EntireRow(1), 0)
JColNum = Application.Match("W Name", rng.EntireRow(1), 0)

Comment: @DZZ We need to see where you're setting `rng` - if there is more to your code, please edit your question and include it.

Comment: @dwirony edited, you can see all now

Comment: All your match variables should be declared as variants and you want to test they do not contain an error value before using.

Comment: And does  rng.EntireRow(1) return the expected search range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rng.Columns.Count` is always going to equal 1,  because you limited `rng` to column A on your `Set` line. Because of this, your second loop will never run (You're trying to loop `4 to 1`, etc.).

Instead, change `Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` to include all columns that your working with, and get the last row value from column A on another line.

Suggested fix:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' Sets data range
Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("S" & lastrow))
```

Comment: The fix indeed changes the number of columns in the {rng} from 1 to 28, in my case, but after implementing the fix when I run the macro I do not see the results, though there is no error message

Comment: @DZZ I fixed a minor typo in my solution, but are you sure you have criteria that meets your requirements? Have you tried stepping through the code using F8? Watch where the highlighted line goes